# Can I import honey to Norway?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, norway

My mother has a few beehives and she is producing honey for home use. I am traveling to Norway in a few days and I'd like to bring one jar (1 kg) of honey to my friend there. I am a resident of Bosnia and Herzegovina, which is not part of the [EEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area).

I've found [this document](http://www.cbi.nl/?pag=85&doc=1887&typ=mid_document), but I think this is related to operating an export business and importing your products to Norway.

What is the relevant Norwegian border legislation in my case? Also note that my first entrance to the EU will be in Frankfurt, Germany.

Comment: As an aside: Putting "Honey" onto your list of things you want to import into the US (and possibly Canada) cab land you on the detailed-inspection lane at immigration, because they're worried that you may be importing honeycombs - honey itself is processed enough so that you can import it (for personal use) without problems. Just don't put it into your carry-on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When importing food to Norway, you are not only affected by custom regulations (they are usually relevant when it comes to taxation of products), but you also have to adhere to the regulations from the [Norwegian Food Safety Authority (Mattilsynet)](http://www.mattilsynet.no/portal/page?_pageid=54,40103&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL&language=english).

[The EU regulation 206/2009](http://www.mattilsynet.no/mattilsynet/multimedia/archive/00049/Engelsk_utgave_206-2_49807a.pdf) is in effect in Norway and tells (page 12, paragraph 5) that you can bring 2kg of honey for personal consumption from BaH (other countries except the EU, Croatia, Faeroe Islands, Greenland or Iceland).

Are you staying in transit in Frankfurt? If you do, you'll probably go through passport control in Frankfurt anyway (entering Schengen) and customs in Oslo. If you have to go through customs in Frankfurt, [the same EU regulation](http://www.zoll.de/DE/Privatpersonen/Reisen/Reisen-nach-Deutschland/Einschraenkungen/Tiere-und-Pflanzen/Schutz-Tierseuchen/Regelungen-Erzeugnisse-tierischen-Ursprungs/regelungen-erzeugnisse-tierischen-ursprungs.html) is in effect in Germany as well. Be aware that it is not allowed to import honeycomb to Germany, as it is counted as a part of the bee colony.

Also remember that you are not allowed to bring honey in your hand luggage, but that you have to put it in checked luggage.

Answer (score 15):

You will find your answers on the website of the [Norwegian customs authority](http://www.toll.no/templates_TAD/Article.aspx?id=195294&epslanguage=en).

In my interpretation, **you can import this honey to Norway**, because:

- *the goods are for you or are a private gift and not intended for sale or commercial use*
- *you bring the goods with you, either on your person or in your luggage*
- The value is less than NOK 6,000 (approx. EUR 815).

(Note that bringing dairy products from outside the EEA is **not** permitted)

Enjoy Norway, it's a fantastic country!